# 1 Byte Register broken into 2 Nibble outputs not working VHDL/ModelSim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus

I have made a 1 byte instruction register in VHDL.  Instead of having a 1 byte output, I have created an upper nibble output and a lower nibble output.  The lower nibble output is special because it uses a tri state buffer.  It has this because it connects to the main bus.  The upper nibble does not as it feeds directly to the control circuit and does not need high impedence.  For some reason, I can't get the lower nibble to output anything.  The upper nibble seems to work fine.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;   --This is required when doing additions to STD_LOGIC_VECTORs

ENTITY INST_REG_SAP_1 IS 

    --LiN is the load signal.  It is active low 
    --Clk is the clock for the register
    --Din is the register input bus
    --EiN is the enable signal for the low nibble.
    --HighNibble is the high nibble output
    --LowNibble is the low nibble output

    PORT(
    LiN, Clk, EiN: IN STD_LOGIC;
    Din: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    HighNibble: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    LowNibble: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));

END INST_REG_SAP_1;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF INST_REG_SAP_1 IS


BEGIN
    PROCESS(LiN, Clk, EiN)
    VARIABLE tempLowNibble: unsigned(3 DOWNTO 0);

    BEGIN

        IF(rising_edge(Clk)) THEN

            IF(LiN='0') THEN
                HighNibble<=Din(7 DOWNTO 4);
                tempLowNibble:=unsigned(Din(3 DOWNTO 0));
            END IF;

        END IF;

        IF(EiN='1') THEN
            LowNibble<=(OTHERS=>'Z');
        ELSIF(EiN='0') THEN
            LowNibble<=Std_logic_vector(tempLowNibble);
        END IF;

    END PROCESS;

END Behavioral;
```

Here is the testbench

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity TB_INST_REG_SAP_1 is
end TB_INST_REG_SAP_1;

architecture test of TB_INST_REG_SAP_1 is

--create time constant
constant CLOCK_PERIOD: time:=2 us;

--create signals for every port
signal Clk: std_logic;
signal LiN: std_logic;
signal EiN: std_logic;
signal Din: std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
signal HighNibble: std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 4);
signal LowNibble: std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);

begin

dut: entity work.INST_REG_SAP_1
port map(Clk=>Clk,
    LiN=>LiN,
    EiN=>EiN,
    Din=>Din,
    HighNibble=>HighNibble);

--simulate the clock
ClkSimulation: process
BEGIN

    FOR count IN 1 TO 32 LOOP
        Clk<= '0';
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD/2;
        Clk<='1';
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD/2;
    END LOOP;

END PROCESS ClkSimulation;



--simulate the load (LiN)
loadSimulation: process
BEGIN

    LiN<='1';
    wait for  4 us;
    LiN<='0';
    wait for 4 us;
    LiN<='1';
    wait for 4 us;
    LiN<='0';
    wait;

END PROCESS loadSimulation;

--simulate the Low Nibble Enable (EiN)
enableSimulation: process
BEGIN

    EiN<='0';
    wait for  20 us;
    EiN<='1';
    wait;

END PROCESS enableSimulation;


--simulate the Din
DinSimulation: process
variable temp: unsigned(7 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    Din<="10000000";
    temp:="10000000";
    wait for 4 us;

    FOR count IN 1 TO 8 LOOP
        temp:=temp+1;
        Din<=Std_logic_vector(temp);
        wait for 4 us;
    END LOOP;
    wait;

END PROCESS DinSimulation;  



end architecture test;
```

Here is the output.  Notice no output from the lower nibble.

[image]

Comment: You have the ability to [probe down into DUT in your simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGFt1.jpg) during debugging, where you'd find the port itself has something besides 'U's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your simulation, you forgot to map `LowNibble`.

This:

```
port map(Clk=>Clk,
    LiN=>LiN,
    EiN=>EiN,
    Din=>Din,
    HighNibble=>HighNibble);
```

should be

```
port map(Clk=>Clk,
    LiN=>LiN,
    EiN=>EiN,
    Din=>Din,
    HighNibble=>HighNibble,
    LowNibble=>LowNibble);
```